# Make Effects in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

How to make a zoom-in effect using ffmpeg. I need to create a video with a single image with Zoom-in as effect using FFMPEG. The Zoom-in should be bit slow. I have searched in the document and could find a sample. Can I get a command line sample?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for the comment. I need a sample FFMPEG command to make a video with zoom effect, I couldnt see any eamples over the doc. Is it possible in FFMPEG. I have seen lot of question related to FFMPEG, which looks similarr to mine(but not stating the same problem), and thats the reason I posted here.

Comment: maybe ask on superuser